# How do I get a single string from a single branch in Firebase and put it on an HTML text box and update it?

Tags: jquery, firebase

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var RPMSPEED = firebase.database().ref().child("RPM");
    RPMSPEED.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateRPMSPEED(postElement, snapshot.val());
    $( "#rpm1" ).text(snapshot.val())
      //What I'm trying to write to.
    });
});
```

In the section where it displays the element ID after the .text area is what I'm trying to write to but right now it just returns nothing to the text box.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZzYZ.png) <--Database Snapshot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Firebase database [`.on` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#on), which `Listens for data changes at a particular location.` So it might not run immediately after the HTML page loads (unless there is coincidentally a database change at that RPM path).

Replacing `.on` with `.once` may make that data retrieval work as expected. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) is a section of the web guides that goes over `.once`